# Obtaining the outcome of a LINQ Select Query and assigning it to a string

Tags: linq

I wrote this little function to get the user email by ID:

```
    public string GetUserEmailByID(int UserID)
    {
        string email = "";
        var query = (
                 from c in dbContext.Users
                 where (c.ID == UserID)
                 select new
                 {
                   email = c.Email,
                 }
             );
        return email;
        //   return query.ToString();
    }
```

And then I wrote this test for it:

```
    [Test]
    public void ShouldGetUserEmailByUserIDVerifyItIsCorrect()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual("useremail@test.com", userRepository.GetUserEmailByID(4));
    }
```

The test failed becaust it was expecting "useremail@test.com" but was string.empty.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var query = (
         from c in dbContext.Users
         where (c.ID == UserID)
         select new
         {
           email = c.Email,
         }
     );
```

This is just a query declaration, for a query that returns a list of anonymous type object with just one property called `email`. **It has nothing to do with your `email` local variable.**

And what's maybe even more important, you're just declaring the query definition, but don't execute it at all!

Try this instead:

```
public string GetUserEmailByID(int UserID)
{
    return (from c in dbContext.Users
             where (c.ID == UserID)
              select c.Email).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: Thank you this solved the issue. I am actually new to Linq and I am learning it. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

The email variable you are returning is the empty string, instead you want the property of one of the object inside of the `IEnumerable<T>` query.
You can change your code with:

```
public string GetUserEmailByID(int UserID)
{
    var query = (
             from c in dbContext.Users
             where (c.ID == UserID)
             select c.Email
         );
    return query.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

This way query will be a `IEnumerable<string>`, so you just have to take the first element, or the default one there're none.

Comment: Thank you, the test failed with this because it was expecting useremail@test.com but was "{ Email = useremail@test.com}"

Apparently the table header is being drawn with the query result, how to do I make sure that only the 'table cell' is being obtained?

Comment: Can be event shorter: return dbContext.Users.Single(u => t.Id == UserId).Email

Comment: @Nikolay I guess the point is to write easy to read and understand ( and obviously working) code, not the shortest possible one :)

Comment: @Nikolay furthermore, that code may return an exception if there's no user with Id equal to UserId